# Mapping Java Array to Frege

Tags: java, arrays, frege

Lets say I'd like to map the Java code:

```
package mypackage;

class A {
    public String[] values() {
       return new String[]{"one", "two"};
    }
}
```

To its Frege counterpart:

```
data AA = pure native mypackage.A where
    native values :: AA -> [String]
```

At the moment Frege complains with:

```
error: incompatible types: String[] cannot be converted to TList
```

How can I map a Java array to Frege ?

Comment: Not only Frege complains—the Java code is invalid as well. Ironically for the same reason. Arrays and Lists are different types…

Comment: My mistake. I didn't copy/paste. I really meant an array. Thanks Ingo for fixing the example :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message is actually from the Java compiler.

The Frege type that corresponds to a Java array

```
Foo[]
```

is

```
JArray Bar
```

where `Bar` is the Frege type that corresponds to `Foo`.

So, in your case it should be

```
JArray String
```

Note that this is an immutable array from the Frege point of view.
If you want a mutable array, use

```
Mutable s (JArray String)
```

but, of course, it can only be used in the ST monad.

Here is the link to the relevant online doc: http://www.frege-lang.org/doc/frege/prelude/PreludeArrays.html
Because this is part of Prelude, you don't need to import anything to use it.